# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_user_agents'

Tags: django

I am using [this](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents) library to understand if user is coming from PC or mobile but I am getting this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_user_agents'`.Does anyone know the solution to this problem? I am using Django 3 +.

Comment: upgrading pip and reinstalling worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

`pip3 install django-user-agents`

Answer (score 0):

Do a `pip install django-user-agents` and make sure that it is in installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # Other apps...
    'django_user_agents',
)
```

You should be good to go after those steps.